# How to get the same instance of a directive when using injection tokens in Angular?

Tags: angular

I'm building a component, `FeatureComponent`, for a library I distribute in Angular. This component has a directive that is dependency-injected into its constructor that provides some custom animation logic on the component. This is good, and it works, but it hardcodes the component to requiring a dependency to this specific directive, like so:

```js
@Directive({
    selector: 'animDirective'
})
export class AnimDirective { ... }

@Component({
    selector: '[feature-component]'
})
export class FeatureComponent {

    // Provides a reference to the `AnimDirective` instance on the component selector in the temple.
    constructor(private animDirective: AnimDirective) {}
}
```

This is then consumed, and `FeatureComponent` receives the instance of `AnimDirective` in its constructor that is bound to its selector:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `<form [animDirective] feature-component></form>`
})
export class AppComponent { ... }
```

What I want is to make this relationship more loosely coupled, and for `FeatureComponent` to accept *any* compatible directive by using an `InjectionToken` in its constructor, rather than directly injecting a concrete instance of `AnimDirective`. For example, I want to inject an interface, `AnimatesFeatures` instead, so I could have multiple choices in how the `FeatureComponent` is animated:

```js
export class AnimDirective implements AnimatesFeatures {}
export class FlashyDirective implements AnimatesFeatures {}
```

I've tried doing this to `FeatureComponent`:

```js
@Component({
    selector: '[feature-component]'
})
export class FeatureComponent {
    constructor(@Inject('ANIMATES_FEATURES') directive: AnimatesFeatures) {}
}
```

And then consuming it like so by providing `FlashyDirective` from my parent `AppComponent`:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `<form [flashyDirective] feature-component></form>`,
    providers: [{
       provide: 'ANIMATES_FEATURES', useClass: FlashyDirective
    }]
})
export class AppComponent { ... }
```

However, the instance of the directive that `FeatureComponent` receives is of a different instance to the one provided in the `AppComponent` template, and therefore, the `FeatureComponent` is unable to manipulate its appearance properly. How can I use an injection token to loosely couple this functionality, while still ensuring the `FeatureComponent` receives the same instance of the directive that is in the `AppComponent` template?

Answer (score 0):

Based on further reading on how Angular's DI works, it appears it's not possible to inject the same directive reference as a template directly into an associated component's constructor, when that directive is provided by a `@Inject()` decorator to enable loose coupling.

[I have instead used the `exportAs` property on the `@Directive()` decorator](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-take-advantage-of-the-exportas-property-81374ce24d26) to provide a component template reference, and then pass that as an input to the `FeatureComponent`, like so:

```js
/**
 * Directive being provided
 */
@Directive({
   selector: '[flashyDirective]',
   exportAs: 'flashy'
})
export class FlashyDirective { ... }

/**
 * FeatureComponent expecting an animation directive.
 */
@Component(...)
export class FeatureComponent {
  // ...
 
  @Input() public animator: AnimatesFeatures;
 
  // ...
}

/**
 * AppComponent
 */
@Component({
   selector: 'app',
   template: `
     <form [flashyDirective] #flashyRef=flashy feature-component [animator]="flashy"></form>
   `
})
export class AppComponent { ... }
```

Unfortunately, it’s quite a verbose solution, but this allows both `AppComponent` and `FeatureComponent` to have access to the same instance of a directive that provides the expected functionality over an interface.